# Switching profiles AWS Secret Manager - .Net Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-sdk, aws-secrets-manager, aws-sdk-net

I am trying to switch profiles in code using appsettings.json for a .net core web service.
If I new up an instance of the client in code eg:

```
        using var client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient();
        client.ListSecretsAsync(listRequest, default)
                                    .GetAwaiter()
                                    .GetResult();
```

this takes the default profile that was set up and works fine.

Instead of using the default profile, I want to control the profile from json file.  I am trying to follow this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/latest/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html

Instead of newing up the client, I am using dependency injection

```
    public SecretsService(IAmazonSecretsManager secretsManagerClient)
    {
        _secretsManagerClient = secretsManagerClient;
    }
```

Here is the config:

```
    "AWS": {
      "Profile": "default",
      "Region": "us-east-2"
     }
```

When I make a call using,

```
    _secretsManagerClient.ListSecretsAsync(listRequest, default)
                                    .GetAwaiter()
                                    .GetResult();
```

it gives an exception

**No such host is known. (secretsmanager.defaultregion.amazonaws.com:443)**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check your appsettings.Development.json file. Some templates have the region set as DefaultRegion and so you have to either update it or remove it to let appsettings.json take precedence.